# VB.NET Using speech marks to put an argument into a string

Tags: sql, vb.net, syntax

In a function, I need to use the argument to change what an SQL query does. Normally I would try to use both ("") and ('') to be able to put the argument into the query, however because the query already has both forms of marks in, it won't let me add an extra set in.

Here is an example of the current code without the change:

```
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [Hiragana List] WHERE Pronunciation='A';"
    Dim instruction = New SqlCommand(query, connection)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = instruction
    da.Fill(HiraganaList)
```

And this is what I want to do in the function:

```
Sub characterChecked(ByVal character As String)
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [Hiragana List] WHERE Pronunciation='character';"
    Dim instruction = New SqlCommand(query, connection)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = instruction
    da.Fill(HiraganaList)
```

The issue arises in the second block of code where currently, "character" needs to be an argument and separated from the query, however it cannot be separated using speech marks ("") so that the query line would become:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [Hiragana List] WHERE Pronunciation='"character"';
```

The result off this is that a "Character constant must contain exactly one character".

I was hoping that using a function to increase the readability of the code would be good programming practise seeing as the alternative would be to repeat the same declarative code with the syllable (in the original example "A") for all of the Hiragana in the Japanese language. Any way around or method to let me use the speech marks here would be incredibly useful.

Comment: Ironically, it seems that the character argument is displayed as I want it to be displayed, however Visual Studio won't accept the syntax as it currently is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate all the strings: query upto the first single quote, `character` variable and query after the `character` variable.

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [Hiragana List] WHERE Pronunciation='" & character & "';"
```

What you are intending to do (expecting the compiler to understand that part of a string is actually a variable) is not supported by VB.NET.

NOTE: as highlighted by Mitch Wheat, the best approach to deal with variable SQL queries is relying on parameterised queries. The whole point of this answer is highlighting the reason for the error you got and how to deal with string manipulation/concatenation in VB.NET.

Comment: Plus, better to use parameterised queries

Comment: @MitchWheat I haven't said anything about the OP's code regarding SQL; but about the OP's code regarding string manipulation. Although this is a certainly worthy comment.

Comment: The indea behind the function is to take data from a SQL table within Visual Studio and then insert it into a new SQL table. String manipulation was where I was having the problem though. Thanks for the clear response :)